# Discord.py shard connection variable with print statement

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, sharding

**KEEP IN MIND IM USING PYTHON NOT JAVASCRIPT**

I am using discord.py and I recently added sharding to my bot. I really wanted to make it so that whenever a shard starts up it says in the console that shard number (number) started. That way I can know which shards are starting and it will be REALLY useful for the project that I am doing. This is my code for my sharding so far:

```
# creating the discord bot
client = commands.AutoShardedBot(shard_count=2, command_prefix = '$')
```

So I wanted something like a variable that I can say in a print statement kinda like this example below, I just need to know how to make a variable or something like that where I can put it in a print statement.

```
print("Shard number "+(shard_id_ready)+" has started.")
```

so that way if shard 5 started it would say

> Shard number 5 has started.

I've looked everywhere and I can't find an example that is in python and not javascript

**KEEP IN MIND IM USING PYTHON NOT JAVASCRIPT**

Comment: "KEEP IN MIND IM USING PYTHON NOT JAVASCRIPT" - We get you, you tagged your question as Python, its a very simple thing to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`on_shard_connect`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_connect#discord.on_shard_connect) and/or [`on_shard_ready`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_connect#discord.on_shard_connect). Ready is for when the shard is properly connected and is able to do things in discord, while connect is for when the shard gets to the connection to discord.

```py
@client.event
async def on_shard_ready(shard_id):
    print(f'Shard #{shard_id} is ready')
```

Comment: OMG thank you so much because i tried this earlier but i did it wrong and now I finally know how!

Comment: it only says the message for the first shard that starts. edit-nvm i think it just said that cause it only needed one shard for now